Best way to write real time data to a Postgres table in batches
I am working with a C# program that is subscribing to options contract data with the updates coming in on multiple threads. I would like to run analytics every minute or so, so I was planning on storing the trades as the come in, in a ConcurrentQueue<PriceSub> trades. I have my current implementation below which is a function that will attempt to write the trades in batches whenever I call it. Is this sufficient? Or is there a better way to do this? It currently works for low volume, but unsure how it will hold up on large volumes of updates.
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;

public struct PriceSub
{
    public DateTime _timestamp;
    public string _name;
    public string _term;
    public DateTime? _expiration;
    public string _type;
    public string _product;
    public decimal? _strike;
    public ulong _instrumentID;

    public decimal _price;
    public decimal _userTV;
    public decimal _midImpliedTV;
    public string _theoPrice;

    public decimal _userVol;
    public decimal _midImpliedVol;

    public decimal _quantity;
    public decimal _totalQuanity;
    public decimal _openInterest;

    public long _thread;
}

public class TradeWriter
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<PriceSub> _trades;
    private string _connectionString;

    public TradeWriter(ConcurrentQueue<PriceSub> trades, string connectionString)
    {
        _trades = trades;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public async Task WriteTradesToDbAsync(int batchSize)
    {
        List<PriceSub> batch = new List<PriceSub>();

        // Dequeue trades in batches
        while (batch.Count < batchSize && _trades.TryDequeue(out var trade))
        {
            batch.Add(trade);
        }

        // If there are trades to write, proceed with batch insertion
        if (batch.Count > 0)
        {
            await InsertTradesBatchAsync(batch);
        }
    }

    private async Task InsertTradesBatchAsync(List<PriceSub> tradesBatch)
    {
        // SQL query for batch insert
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO es_options_daily 
            (_timestamp, _name, _term, _expiration, _type, _product, _strike, _instrumentID,
            _price, _userTV, _midImpliedTV, _theoPrice, _userVol, _midImpliedVol, 
            _quantity, _totalQuantity, _openInterest, _thread) 
            VALUES 
            (@timestamp, @name, @term, @expiration, @type, @product, @strike, @instrumentID,
            @price, @userTV, @midImpliedTV, @theoPrice, @userVol, @midImpliedVol,
            @quantity, @totalQuantity, @openInterest, @thread)";

        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection, transaction))
                {
                    foreach (var trade in tradesBatch)
                    {
                        // Add parameters for each trade in the batch
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", trade._timestamp);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", trade._name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", trade._term);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expiration", trade._expiration.HasValue ? (object)trade._expiration.Value : DBNull.Value);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", trade._type);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", trade._product);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strike", trade._strike.HasValue ? (object)trade._strike.Value : DBNull.Value);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instrumentID", trade._instrumentID);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", trade._price);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userTV", trade._userTV);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@midImpliedTV", trade._midImpliedTV);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theoPrice", trade._theoPrice);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userVol", trade._userVol);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@midImpliedVol", trade._midImpliedVol);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", trade._quantity);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalQuantity", trade._totalQuanity);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@openInterest", trade._openInterest);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thread", trade._thread);

                        // Execute insert for the current trade in the batch
                        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                        // Clear parameters for the next trade
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }

                // Commit the transaction after batch insertion
                await transaction.CommitAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}


"unsure how it will hold up on large volumes of updates" try it out

It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at CodeReview.SE. Remember to read their requirements.

You have a producer-consumer scenario, and for implementing this scenario the correct collection to use is either the BlockingCollection<T> (synchronously), or the Channel<T> (asynchronously). The problem with your current implementation is that the WriteTradesToDbAsync method will exit as soon as the _trades collection is temporarily empty. Both of the aforementioned collections deal with this problem by making the consumer wait while the collection is empty, until either a new item is added or the producer completes adding items in the collection (they both have a Complete method).
Here is a simplified usage example with the _trades being a BlockingCollection<PriceSub>:
public async Task WriteTradesToDbAsync(int batchSize)
{
    foreach (PriceSub trade in _trades.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        await InsertTradeAsync(trade);
    }
}

Since you are inserting the trades in batches, you can find in this answer a GetConsumingEnumerableBatch extension method for the BlockingCollection<T>, that you could use like this:
public async Task WriteTradesToDbAsync(int batchSize)
{
    foreach (PriceSub[] trades in _trades.GetConsumingEnumerableBatch())
    {
        await InsertTradesBatchAsync(trades);
    }
}

Using a Channel<T> instead of a BlockingCollection<T> should be conceptually better, because it waits asynchronously while the collection is empty, and so it optimizes the use of threads. Writing a ReadAllBatches extension method for the ChannelReader<T> with similar behavior with the GetConsumingEnumerableBatch shouldn't be very difficult. You could look at this question as a starting point. Before switching to a channel, you should first familiarize yourself with the asynchronous sequences (the IAsyncEnumerable<T> interface and the await foreach statement).
